# XMLPullParser android colon tags

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I have found several questions of the name question, but can't get any of them to work. What I want is to get the url of the media:thumbnail tag:

```
<media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/6013/production/_88159542_3e6f2bc3-16a3-407d-9e07-62bae1fa755e.jpg"/>
```

Above the example of such tag

```
private void handleText(String text) {
            String xmlText = text;
            if (currentEntry != null && currentTag != null) {
                if (currentTag.equals(TITLE)) {
                    currentEntry.setTitle(xmlText);
                } else if (currentTag.equals(DESC)) {
                    currentEntry.setDescription(xmlText);
                } else if (currentTag.equals(LINK)) {
                    currentEntry.setLink(xmlText);
                } else if (currentTag.equals(IMAGE)) {
                    currentEntry.setImage("test");
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried several things as:

xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "url"); and set the image as that. However I noticed that I am not even getting in that else if clause. I tried several values on the IMAGE variable like:

- media:thumbnail
- media
- thumbnail

I have also set namespace aware:

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

What am I doing wrong?

parser:

```
XmlPullParser xpp;
int eventType;

protected List<Entry> doInBackground(String... string) {
    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml?edition=uk")), "UTF_8");

        eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                handleStartTag(xpp.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                currentTag = null;
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                handleText(xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Comment: What is your `IMAGE` value?

Comment: Either: media:thumbnail , media or thumbnail

Comment: Can you post the code of your parser?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I systemed out the start tags it was parsing and it showed up as: thumbnail. So I changed my IMAGE constant to have the value of "thumbnail". It never came in the thumbnail clause since the handleText method only handles found text in a tag. Since media:thumbnail has no text only attributes with values I needed to handle it in the handleStartTag method. There I could say if the current tag name equals "thumbnail" get the attribute value of url and setImage as that value.